# Retrieving users city from Facebook Graph api

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook-graph-api, swift3, nsdictionary

City is a field of location but I just can't seem to retrieve it. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/location", parameters: ["fields": "city"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            let location = result as! NSDictionary
            let city = location.value(forKey: "city") as! String
            print(city)
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. You must use location{location}.

```
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "location{location}"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                self.alertTheUser(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
                print(error)
            }else{
                let fbDetails = result as! NSDictionary
                let location : NSDictionary! = fbDetails.value(forKey: "location") as! NSDictionary
                let locationContents : NSDictionary! = location.value(forKey: "location") as! NSDictionary
                self.registerCityField.text = locationContents.value(forKey: "city") as? String
                self.registerStateField.text = locationContents.value(forKey: "state") as? String
                self.registerCountryField.text = locationContents.value(forKey: "country") as? String
            }
        })
```

Comment: Learn something new today...Great...!

Answer (score 0):

You can not get City Name directly from Graph API so you can only get the location of user. From that location you can get the city name as well.

To get the location you need set permission and fields Like Below :

```
//Permission
["public_profile", "email", "user_location"]

//Fields for parameter
["fields":"email,location"]
```